# My Java Program won't Compile

Tags: java, arrays, compilation

As I just stated above this program won't compile.  In my IDE, TextPad, it gives me 2 errors in the createArray method.  It says that both a right bracket and semicolon are expected in my return statement when I indeed have them there.  Could someone help me out here?

```
public class Driver
{
    private static int size;
    private static String somePromptMessage;
    private static boolean validInput;
    private static String userData;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        validInput = false;
        BufferedReader keyboard;
        keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int result;
        do
        {
            somePromptMessage = "Enter an integer";
            System.out.println(somePromptMessage);
            String userData;
            userData = keyboard.readLine();
            System.out.println(createArray(10));
            try
            {
                result = Integer.parseInt(userData);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
            System.out.println("Value entered is invalid, try again");
            }
        }
        while(!validInput);
        {
            return result;
        }

    }

    public static void print(int[]x)
    {
        System.out.println("The array contains" + size + "elements");
        for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }
    }

    private static int[] createArray(int size)
    {
        return int[size];
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget the closing bracket at the end of the class?

Comment: I do have it there, it just didn't get into this code here as I have another method that I have commented out now for the time being.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the enclosing `}` for the class, but I'll assume that one is a copy-paste issue.

The actual problem I see is that you want

```
return new int[size];
```

instead of

```
return int[size];
```

in your `createArray` function.

Comment: Yes, that enclosing brace is a copy-paste issue because there is another method I have in this class, but it isn't included right now since I've commented it out for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I see an extra simi-colon here:

```
while(!validInput);
{
        return result;
 }
```

Update: It was brought to my attention that this is actually a do while so why the extra braces around the return statement?

Comment: It looks like the semi-colon is because the `while` is part of a do-while, but that does also beg the question of why `return result` is in braces.

Comment: That is correct, Dennis.  I know that the return of the while of my do-while doesn't necessarily need to be in braces because it's only 1 line, but I just put them there anyways.

Comment: You should take them off it doesn't make sense to have them inside brackets, that'll just confuse people

Answer (score 0):

remove braces after while across `return result;` as it is `do-while`:

```
do
{
    somePromptMessage = "Enter an integer";
    System.out.println(somePromptMessage);
    String userData;
    userData = keyboard.readLine();
    System.out.println(createArray(10));
    try
    {
        result = Integer.parseInt(userData);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("Value entered is invalid, try again");
    }
}
while(!validInput);
return result;
```